# trouble with installing go mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm new to Go and trying to install mongodb driver following this tutorial:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang--mongodb--starting-and-setup

results in the error below.

```
[root@real-rs-001 ~]# go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver
package go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver: no Go files in /root/go/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver
```

Comment: Try `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo` (from [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver#readme-installation)). What version of go are you using?

Comment: @Brits It's go1.15.8. ```go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo``` works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments; using the command provided in the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver#readme-installation) worked:

```sh
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```

Note: `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` worked fine on my machine (go 1.14 & 1.16).